# Error while setting content in dom reader in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am using xml and qt for first time and trying to read an xml using a DOM reader in qt, but it shows an error. Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Summary>
<no_of_blank_spaces>13</no_of_blank_spaces>
</Summary>
```

MY DOM READER CODE which I wrote:

```
void DOMReader:arseFile(QString fileName)
{    
    QFile file(fileName);

    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) 
    {
        qDebug() << "Not able to open the file";
        return;
    }

     qDebug()<<"///////////////////////////"<<file.isOpen(); // IT SHOWS OPEN here!!!!!!!

    QString errMsg;
    int errLine;
    int errCol;

    QDomDocument doc;

    if (!doc.setContent(&file,false,&errMsg,&errLine,&err Col))
    {
        qDebug() << "errMsg : " << errMsg;
        qDebug() << "errLine : " << errLine;
        qDebug() << "errCol : " << errCol;

        qDebug() << "Error in XML File format" <<endl;
        return;
    }

    QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();
    if (root.tagName() != "Summary")
    {
        qDebug() << "Error in root" << endl;
        return;
    }

    processRoot(root);
    return;
}

void DOMReader:rocessRoot(QDomElement root)
{
    qDebug()<< "***********in dom*********" << endl;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> errorMSg:-"unexpected end of file" errLINe:1 errCol:1 Error in XML
>   Format..

I should get the output:

> "***********in dom*********"

So it is not reading the DOM document properly, please kindly help me through...

Comment: Please, add output of `qDebug() << file.readAll();` right after the marked line, which checks `isOpen`.

Comment: IMHO, the problem is in your `fileName`. It isn't pointing to your xml file. I suppose, it contains relative path, which is calculated from a wrong place.

Comment: QString filename="D:/summary.xml";
QFile file1(filename);

file1.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::ReadOnly );

//qDebug()<<"*************************"<<file1.isOpen();

QXmlStreamWriter xmlWriter(&file1);
  xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting(true);
  xmlWriter.writeStartDocument();


    xmlWriter.writeStartElement("Summary");
    xmlWriter.writeTextElement("no_of_blank_spaces",QString::number(blank));

Comment: xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
      xmlWriter.writeEndDocument();

Comment: file1.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::ReadOnly ); - this is wrong, you need to use only one of open flags.

Comment: After checking with Qt's help - this is not actually wrong. So, if you have problems with writing xml you should ask another question.

Comment: then also it shows the same...

Comment: Ran your example on linux (with different path, of course) - works fine. May be your are forbidden to write on `D:`?